# Using one SP insert data into two tables in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have two tables one is Sales and second one is SalesDetails,
Sales table will add data at ones only and SalesDetails will add multiple times so how can I call SalesDetails multiple times and Sale only at once using one procedure call
Please Help me.
Thank You in Advanced.

Here is my Store Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addSalesAndSalesDetails`(
in invoiceno nvarchar(30),
in client_id int,
in p_id int,
in qty int,
in unit_price decimal(18,2),
in total_price decimal(18,2),
in sub_total decimal(18,2),
in gst_per int,
in gst_amt decimal(18,2),
in discount_amt decimal(18,2),
in grand_total decimal(18,2),
in s_date date) 
BEGIN 
     insert into salesDetails values(
          default, invoiceno, 
          client_id, p_id, qty,
          unit_price, total_price,
          s_date);

     insert into sales values(
          default, invoiceno, client_id,
          sub_total, gst_per, gst_amt,
          discount_amt, grand_total, 
          s_date);
END
```

Comment: How is this related to Java?

Comment: Coz m working on web application and backend language is Java